# Can't display Google Map with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

When run, if I click the link at the bottom of the index page to get to the map page, I see the map briefly, filling a quarter of the screen, before it vanishes. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code for the index page, which creates the map page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css"/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>          
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initialize(){
                if(!window.navigator.onLine){
                    alert("An internet connection is required to use the MetPetDB App. Please find a connection and reopen the app.");
                    var element = document.getElementById("mainPage");
                    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
                    document.getElementById("mainBody").innerHTML = "<p>An internet connection is required to use this app.</p>";
                }
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">   </script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // When map page opens get location and display map
            $('.page-map').live("pagecreate", function() {
                initializeMap(42,-73);
            });
            function initializeMap(lat,lng) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="mainBody" onload="initialize()">
        <div id="mainPage" data-role="page" data-theme="e">
            <div data-role="header">
                <!-- <img src="headerlogo.png" />-->
                <br />
                <p style="text-align:center">To begin searching for samples, select one of the following search methods.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" style="height: 100%;">
                <a data-role="button" data-theme="a" href="useMyLocation.html">Use My Location</a>
                <a data-role="button" data-theme="a" href="InputCoordinates.html">Input Coordinates</a>
                <a data-role="button" data-theme="a" href="selectRegion.html">Select Region</a>
                <a href="dragMap.html">Testing</a>
           </div>
       </div>
    </body>  
</html>
```

And here is the map page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="e" class="page-map" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            <div data-role="header"><h1>Map Page</h1></div>
            <div data-role="content" style="width:100%; height:100%; padding:0;"> 
                <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hR9x/)

I took your code, simplified it (using a single page template instead of the multi page one, but just to make it easier for jsfiddle) and moved all scripts inside the head.

Also be careful with phonegap, you should handle the onDeviceReady event, and not the body onload event. Even then there's a [different method there](http://www.neotericdesign.com/blog/checking-the-online-status-with-phonegap-jquery) to check if you're online.

Comment: See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5hR9x/3/   Now the map appears, but it takes over everything. Absolute positioning should be relative to the first parent element, which would be the content div, but it's being positioned relative to body instead. Do you know why that is? Also note how the map only appears at 25% size, and doesn't allow itself to be expanded. This confuses me quite a bit.